# Iterate through 2 objects and multiply some properties if there is a match

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have an object like this

```
Object {SD00002:1,SD00011:3,SD00002:6}
```

The values of the properties and set automatically.
Now I have an array of objects like this:
[image]

Now I want to iterate through the 2 objects and multiply "cmimi" property  (which is inside the objects in the array) with the corresponding value of the properties in the first object. The property of the first object is the same with the "kodartikulli" in the array of objects. i want to multiply all the values with "cmimi" and return the sum of all. None of the other questions asked on Stack Overflow seems to help my problem.

Comment: please add the data in text form - and what you have tried. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the array and take the value of `kodartikulli` as key for trhe multiplicator.

```js
var data1 = { SD00002: 1, SD00011: 3, SD00052: 6 },
    data2 = [
        { cmimi: 189.9, kodartikulli: 'SD00002' },
        { cmimi: 99.9,  kodartikulli: 'SD00011' },
        { cmimi: 69.9,  kodartikulli: 'SD00052' }
    ],
    total = data2.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + a.cmimi * (data1[a.kodartikulli] || 0);
    }, 0);
      
console.log(total);
```